Unbind class selector jquery after changing class of a div
I am dynamically altering the class of a div when ajax request completes.
<div id="MyDiv1" class="oldclass">Age</div>

Inside the success function of ajax request  :
 $('.oldclass').click({ alert('I am old'); });

 $('.youngclass').click({ alert('I am young'); });

$.ajax({

........
success: function(){
     $('#MyDiv1').removeAttr('oldclass');

     $('#MyDiv1').addAttr('youngclass'); 
}
});

But still the click oldclass click is working on clicking this div. How do I achieve this without refreshing the whole page.
Jsfiddle demo here

There is neither an oldclass or a youngclass attribute in your code.

@DavidThomas: Between that and the syntax of the click handlers, my guess is this isn't the OP's actual code and is just a hastily written pseudo-example.  Which increases the chances that the OP may move the goal posts here...

Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a Stacksnippet. Right now it sounds like an X/Y problem and .bind has been deprecated since 2016 - You likely want to use the .on delegation

Now I re-read your question, you are looking for removeClass and addlClass  $('#MyDiv1').removeClass('oldclass').addClass('newclass') which is why your code does not work

Please check the js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5dp76mxa/2/

You are using attr when you mean class.
You do need to delegate since you cannot access the element after you change the class otherwise


$(() => {
  // here we delegate from the nearest STATIC container
  $('#container').on('click', '.oldclass', function() {
    alert('I am old');
  });

  $('#container').on('click', '.youngclass', function() {
    alert('I am young');
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#MyDiv1').removeClass('oldclass');
    $('#MyDiv1').addClass('youngclass');
  }, 5000); // click again in 5 seconds
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
Click, wait 5 secs and click again
  <button id="MyDiv1" class="oldclass">Age</button>
</div>



DRYer:


$(() => {
  
  // here we delegate from the nearest STATIC container
  // if you do NOT replace the button in the DOM you can use $('#MyDiv1').'click', function() {
  
  $('#container').on('click', '#MyDiv1', function() { // clicking the button
    alert(`I am ${$(this).is('.youngclass') ? 'young':'old'}`);
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#MyDiv1').removeClass('oldclass');
    $('#MyDiv1').addClass('youngclass');
  }, 5000); // click again in 5 seconds
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Click, wait 5 secs and click again
  <button id="MyDiv1" class="oldclass">Age</button>
</div>




There are a few things wrong in the code shown.  For starters, you're using removeAttr and addAttr where you meant to be using removeClass and addClass.  The values you're changing are classes on the element, not attributes on the element.
Additionally, your syntax for adding click event handlers is entirely wrong.  I'm surprised this isn't producing an error for you, and more to the point this certainly isn't actually showing the alerts when you click but, if anything, would be showing them immediately when the page loads.  It's important that you pay attention to details like that in the resulting behavior when you test your code.
We can correct that syntax by replacing the click handlers entirely anyway...
Event handlers are bound to the element, not to the selector.  One option here would be to use event delegation and bind to a common ancestor element.  The delegated event handler would re-check the selector each time.
For example:
$(document).on('click', '.oldclass', () => alert('I am old'));
$(document).on('click', '.youngclass', () => alert('I am young'));

In this case the click handlers are bound to document rather than to the individual elements.  Any time a click event bubbles up to document it checks the selector provided to see if it matches the element which originated the event.  If it does, the event handler executes.
You don't need to use document, any common ancestor element will work.  For example, if all target elements are children of the same <div> then you can select that <div> instead.  document is just often used in examples because it's always a common ancestor for every element on the page.

thanks, but will "unbind" not work here?

@sqlchild: If you attach the click handlers with .on() then you can remove them with .off().  That would involve a bit more re-structuring of the code and require that you manually maintain those handlers any time you change the classes, so it's more work.  But if that's what you prefer then you can certainly go that route as well.

Also, Is resetting the DOM element dynamically not possible?

@sqlchild: It's not clear to me what you mean by "resetting the DOM element dynamically".

I mean page refresh resets everything , means the event handlers get to know that which  one has to work, so is it not possible to refresh the event handler ?  i can use localStorage database and save that this button is now YOUNG, so on refreshing it will call YOUNG event handler, but I need to do it without refreshing.

@sqlchild: You can certainly remove an element from the page and replace it with a new one.  That new one won't have any handlers attached to it.  That would require you write logic to perform that replacement, maintaining any state of child elements as needed, and re-attaching any event handlers as needed.  Just like with dynamically adding/removing event handlers, it's more work and more potential for bugs.  Those approaches really seem like overkill in this example.

Ok , so you mean if I remove the div, and add NEW DIV using jquery   giving it the same id then wiill it work ? How will I attach the click event to it ..using BIND () ?

@sqlchild: If a <div> has a click handler, and you remove that <div> and replace it with a new one and add a click handler to that new <div> then that new <div> will have a click handler attached to it.  Though it's worth noting that this scenario is precisely why event delegation exists.

IS this write:
$('#MyDiv1').remove(); -----------
$body.append('#MyDiv1');  ------------
$('#MyDiv1').bind('click');

That sounds a LOT like an X/Y problem. Also .bind has been deprecated since 2016

@sqlchild: One way to find out would be to test it.  If that's specifically the problem you are trying to solve, and not the problem you presented in the question, then please update the question to a [mcve] which demonstrates the actual problem you've encountered in your attempt.

I am confused where did I deviate from my post. Could you please help me out. I am trying to just get the alert('I am young')

@sqlchild: Have you attempted the solution proposed in this answer?  Can you demonstrate with a [mcve] in what way your attempt isn't working as expected?

@David Sir, can you please help me out with .on() , .off(), I dont want to use document selector.

See my comment. You just want this in your success $('#MyDiv1').removeClass('oldclass').addClass('newclass')

@mplungjan sir it doesnt works ...https://jsfiddle.net/5dp76mxa/2 , its giving me alert(I am OLD) rather than saying - I AM YOUNG
